# List files which are NOT created/modified on specific dates

Tags: bash, shell, find

I want to list all the files in a folder excluding specific dates.

I tried using `find` commend with `! -newermt` but it looks like its now working.

```
find /home/ubuntu/ -maxdepth 1  ! -newermt "2019-09-17" ! -newermt "2019-08-25" ! -newermt "2019-05-31" ! -newermt "2019-06-30" -type f
```

Ex: 
1.txt created on 2019-09-18

2.txt created on 2019-09-17

3.txt created on 2019-05-19

4.txt created on 2019-01-20

I want to list all the files which are not created on 2019-09-18, 2019-01-20

I want the result should be,

2.txt created on 2019-09-17

3.txt created on 2019-05-19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` is inherently recursive, but you're specifying maxdepth of 1. You could use `ls`:

```sh
ls -lah /home/ubuntu --time-style full-iso | awk '!/2019-01-20|2019-09-18/'
```

If you only want file names:

```sh
ls -lah /home/ubuntu --time-style full-iso | awk '!/2019-01-20|2019-09-18/' | awk 'BEGIN {ORS=""} {split($0,a," "); printf "%s\n",a[9]}'
```